# `hostname -i` address differs from `ifconfig` address

Tags: bash, connection, ip-address, archlinux, hostname

Resolving my local hostname (the one returned by `hostname`) does not yield the right ip address. Why could that be and how do I fix it?

```
$ hostname -i
10.21.16.206

$ ping 10.21.16.206
PING 10.21.16.206 (10.21.16.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.21.16.159 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

$ ifconfig
(...)
inet 10.21.16.159  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.21.19.255
(...)
```

10.21.16.206 != 10.21.16.159

```
$ host 10.21.16.159
 Host 159.16.21.10.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ host 10.21.16.206
 206.16.21.10.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lxka-czc1166cxw.united.domain.

$ resolveip 10.21.16.159
Host name of 10.21.16.159 is lxka-czc1166cxw

$ resolveip 10.21.16.206
Host name of 10.21.16.206 is lxka-czc1166cxw.united.domain
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Edit:

```
$ host $(hostname)
lxka-czc1166cxw.united.domain has address 10.21.16.206
```

Comment: Add output of `host $(hostname)` to your question.

Comment: Done: lxka-czc1166cxw.united.domain has address 10.21.16.206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hostname -i relies on DNS resolution to return the IP address of the given hostname. Either your /etc/hosts or dns resolver return that hostname to the incorrect IP address.

Comment: Don't answer off-topic questions - instead, please flag them
for attention and they will be closed or migrated
appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

from man page of hostname:

> option  -i, --ip-address
>
> Display the network address(es) of the host name. Note that this works only if  the  host  name can be resolved. ***Avoid using this option*;**

use **hostname --all-ip-addresses** or
To use the **hostname -I** option instead of it.